# How can I apply transitions to my elements that have display:none?

Tags: html, css

I have some divs that appear when you hover an image. However, I want to have a transition rather than the images appearing so abruptly. I'm trying to avoid javascript if possible.

```
img {
display: none
}
p.one:hover + img {
display: block;
}
p.two:hover img {
display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmeyf03r/56/

Comment: You can't do transitions on the `display` property. Try the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property) instead.

Comment: Like @BrokenBinary has said, transitions won't work with `display: none`. However, you can use other CSS properties to get the effect you want. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Transitions don't work with `display: none`. You can't fade in an element that's been removed from the page. Similarly, you can't fade out a `display: block` element. With `display`, the element is either in or out.

However, you can still transition your divs with CSS using the `visibility`, `opacity` and `height` properties.

HTML

```
<p class="one">HOVER OVER ME - IMG IS SIBLING</p>
     <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100">
<p class="two">HOVER OVER ME -IMG IS CHILD</p>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100">
```

CSS

```
img {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: height .5s linear, opacity .5s linear;
}

p.one:hover + img {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

p.two:hover + img {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Here's your demo, updated with the code above:
http://jsfiddle.net/nmeyf03r/58/

Comment: Exactly - even if display were animatable, the browser wouldn't know how exactly the author *wants* the transition to look. That's why you have to tell it specifically to fade out the element, or shrink its width/height, or whatever.